# Looking for friendly homework problem generator for linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Once I saw an online paper on designing friendly linear algebra problems. These would be problems where the answers use small integers or such. Now I cannot locate the paper. Any pointers?

Comment: uses small integers? how do you mean that ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis For example, matrices whose exact inverse would not use large numbers/fractions. Gram-Schmidt problems where final vectors end up having small integer components. This is more like a number theory question applied to homework problem design. A similar problem in teaching of calculus is finding cubic polynomials whose roots and roots of derivatives are integers.

Comment: I am only student, but i always thought those problems would be made from the behind. For example a cubic polynomial with nice roots is (x-2) ( x-5) (x+3)  which is the same as $x^3-4x^2-11x -30 $ and so on

Comment: But making sure that the derivative also has also integer roots is a bit tricky. When you go to quartic polynomials you want $f,f',f''$ all have integer roots, and that is not easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking of John Steele's paper, [Setting Linear Algebra Problems](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~jds/Papers/linalg.pdf).